# How to flip an images with a specific direction

Tags: javascript, css, credit-card, flip

I'm still new in coding, please be nice to me :)

Anyway,
I have 2 input texts for [Credit Card](https://jpst.it/1SGt_).
When I click CVV input text it should be flip horizontal left, same as Expiry Year input text should flip horizontal right.
My problem is that i don't know how to put a specific flip direction to this card.

```
<input type="text" Placeholder="Expiration Year" onclick="flip()" />
<input type="text" placeholder="cvv" onclick="flip()" />
<section class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front">1</div>
        <div class="back">2</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
    background: red;
}

.card .back {
    background: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```
function flip() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

Comment: What is happening now when you run this code?

Comment: What I like is, it should not flipped back when I double click the same input text.
I just took an example with some articles here on internet but I didn't find some examples for specific flip direction for that onclick input text.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand, it flips to far? In that case I would apply the same logic for a 'focus out' event on the input; when you leave the field it flips back.

Comment: In addition, you can also refactor your code to only flip if it isn't flipped already.

Comment: This is noted. thanks

Comment: Can you give me some tips for refactoring this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write this in semi-code to just explain the idea.

```
//pass the id of the element you want to flip    
function flip(idToFlip){    
    if(!$('#idToFlip').hasClass('flipped')){
        $('#idToFlip').addClass('flipped');

        //this function can check the state of other elements and place them in the correct state - you will have to write this yourself if needed
        cleanUpOtherElements();
    }
}
//bind this function to a focus-out/blur event to flip it back
function flipBack(idToFlipBack){
    //see above, it's almost the same
}
```

Writing something like this prevents the double-click bug that you  might experience and makes sure that elements don't stay flipped when they shouldn't.

Comment: its still not working :(
I almost banged my self to the wall, still i did not get it